# Spring erro Cors

Tags: spring, cors

I have a problem with the spring Cors.

I get this error on chome:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/informationWS' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

My file WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {   
    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;
    
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }   
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {   
        auth
            .userDetailsService(loginService)
            .passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoderAutentication());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderAutentication() {
        String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
        Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put(idForEncode, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        encoders.put("pbkdf2", new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder());
        encoders.put("scrypt", new SCryptPasswordEncoder());
         
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoders);
        
        return passwordEncoder;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

My file ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/informationWS").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/work").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().denyAll();
    }  
}
```

I tried to work with Cors in the two ways below, but neither of them worked, generating the same error

My file cors

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Cors implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
       registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }
}
```

My file Cors2

```
@Configuration
public class Cors {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilterFilterRegistrationBean(){
        List<String> host = Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200");

        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(host);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", corsConfiguration);

        CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter(source);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> filter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(corsFilter);
        filter.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

        return filter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could try/check:

- check if the application code is executed - maybe server stops execution for some reason, and so your spring code cannot add a header.
- maybe there is preflight request and server does not allow it (so again server stopped execution and your backend code could not send the header)
- maybe you yourself stop script somewhere before the header is added, like `System.exit(0);`
- maybe there is redirect to code which does not add header, for example some exception
- try running the request from Postman - you should not get the error and maybe you will see something surprising.
- does this `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/informationWS")`  really match the request? Maybe there is a way to add wildcard just for testing and see if it works? Are you sending GET request?

More details, technologies different but concept same: https://dariuscoder.com/2021/09/16/how-to-debug-cors/